# How to change read-only permission to set new value of MySQL server system variable

Tags: mysql, database, system-variable

I am new to MySQL; recently I faced this problem while setting a new value for a system variable.

I tried:

```
mysql> set global innodb_ft_min_token_size = 6;
```

but I am getting this error:

```
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'innodb_ft_min_token_size' is a read only variable
```

Is there any way to change the read only permission? I read about [InnoDB parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html) but could not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The site you linked](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html) contains all information needed:

> System variables that are true or false can be enabled at server startup by naming them [...]
>
> System variables that take a numeric value can be specified as --var_name=value on the command line or as var_name=value in option files.
>
> Many system variables can be changed at runtime (see Section 5.1.5.2, “Dynamic System Variables”).

The [`innodb_ft_min_token_size` is not a dynamic variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) so you will have to change the config file `my.cnf` and add `innodb_ft_min_token_size=6`. Alternatively you need to change the startup command of your MySQL server.

After the change you must restart your MySQL server.

Comment: i did these things but still not getting the modified value.

Comment: i was using link file to access the my.cnf now modified the my.cnf inside `/etc` so now, i am able to see the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file(location in your case could be different, do `locate my.cnf` to find the location for your system), add/modify:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2
```

to set the minimum limit to 2.
Don't forget to restart the mysql server and rebuilding the fulltext index. For me, the following worked like a charm.

```
drop index index_stem on  maps;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_stem ON maps(stem_value);
```

Answer (score -3):

As of MySQL 5.7.5, the innodb_buffer_pool_size configuration option can be set dynamically using a SET statement, allowing you to resize the buffer pool without restarting the server. For example:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=402653184;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html