# How to change default_authentication_plugin variable in Amazon Aurora Serverless MySQL 5.7.12

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm using **Amazon Aurora Serverless MySQL cluster**(MySQL 5.7) and I want to change the value of global variable **[default_authentication_plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin)** which is currently set to default ie. *mysql_native_password*

These are the commands I'm using to update the default authentication plugin

```
SET GLOBAL default_authentication_plugin = 'sha256_password'; 
SET @@GLOBAL.default_authentication_plugin = 'sha256_password';
```

I'm getting below error

[image]

From documentation, I can see the default_authentication_plugin is not a dynamic variable.
[image]

Also, I have checked in the DB Cluster Parameter group it's not available there as well.

How do I change the value of **default_authentication_plugin** in this case. Can someone help me?

> This question cannot be duplicate of
> [How to change read-only permission to set new value of MySQL server system variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670855/how-to-change-read-only-permission-to-set-new-value-of-mysql-server-system-varia)
> as I'm using Amazon Aurora Serverless where user don't have access to
> the config files of mysql

Comment: @shadow Can you please help me reopen the issue? My use-case is different than the question against which my question is marked as duplicate. User don't have access to file system incase of Amazon RDS Aurora Serverless

Comment: Changed the duplicate target for a aws specific one. However, you are really on the wrong Q/A site, since SO is about programming, not about configuring databases. The dba sister site of SO is suitable for your question.